# How to backup and restore `ubersvn` data with command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, backup, restore, svn-server

Currently we can backup `ubersvn` server data by going to the web interface, log in, go to Administartor, Backup and follow the UI there.

My need is to do it via a command-line/batch command.

Comment: for ubersvn chimney house release, the GUI backup simply creates an archive (ZIP) of `{conf,tomcat/webapps/ubersvn/META-INF,ubersvn-db}`; I haven't reverse engineered it extensively, but simply backing up `{conf,tomcat,ubersvn-db/ubersvn-db.script,ubersvn-db/ubersvn-db.properties}` should do the trick, on top of a `bin/svnadmin hotcopy --clean-logs repositories/reponame /backup/reponame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a blog on how to back up Subversion repositories here: http://blogs.wandisco.com/2012/03/20/how-to-backup-subversion-repositories/

However, that only backs up the Subversion data and not the uberSVN admin stuff (such as users and teams etc). Currently the only way to back this up is via the uberSVN interface.

If you have any further questions gimme a shout here: http://www.svnforum.org/forums/32-uberSVN-Help-and-Support

Mand

Online Operations, 
WANdisco